# Mock with all valid methods in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have following problem:
I want to test controller if no exception is rised during dispatch, but controller uses external library which has own `phpunit` tests. This library also use external library with own tests and so on...

So my application looks similar to this diagram:

`request -> router -> dispatch -> controller -> view`

If any error occures during this procces. Application throws exception. I want to test controller, but for now I have to write +50 lines of code to mock all object needed.

Image for example that I pass form from controller to `view`.
In `view` I have something like this:

```
<?php echo $form->openTag('form'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->openTag('fieldset'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label('firstName'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->input('firstName'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->errorMessages('firstName'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->closeTag('fieldset'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->openTag('fieldset'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label('gender'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->radio('gender'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->errorMessages('gender'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->closeTag('gender'); ?>
   ...
<?php echo $form->closeTag('form'); ?>
```

Let's say I have form with 20 inputs... Do you get my point? I have to mock all available methods for this form to pass my test.

**It is possible to mock object with all valid methods?**

I mean if there is a way to mock class which will have all methods valid? Without need to define anything.
If application will need object of class `A` it will return object of class `A`.
If application will need array it will return array
etc..

Comment: No, that's not how mocking works - your mocks can't assume to give you what it is you require at run-time, instead you have to direct your mocks and make them return what it is you want to test with at that point in time.

The fact the third party dependency has its own unit tests should give you enough cover here though... you should mock those dependencies and have a range of unit tests, ensuring your controller handles anything those dependencies may return appropriately.

Comment: So, you say I have to write +50 lines of code just to simulate that form works fine?

Answer (score 0):

We know very little of your application context, but by default `$this->createMock(Some::class)` would create a mock of the entire class - no need to mock every method. Then you can define behavior only to certain methods and that's the entire point of mocking. So in your case it would be your form class I guess, and you will have to set it to the view.

But I would ask what are you testing? If you are testing if the form would throw an exception, you wouldn't want to mock it, but execute it and check for exception.

Comment: `...you can define behavior only to certain methods...`, what if I need to define 20 or 25 methods to make it work? I test if my request is dispatched correctly, but I can't test it if elements in view throw errors

Comment: Then your code needs re-approaching because its been written in such a way that it's untestable @user7686493

Comment: @user7686493 why do you mock the form then - you want it to be executed without being mocked and check for exceptions.